# predict.randomForest argument nodes=TRUE

Tags: r, regression, prediction, random-forest

When I do predict on newdata for randomForest (R implementation) and set nodes=TRUE

```
predict(rf, newdata = testset, nodes = TRUE)
```

what is returned?

It says it returns an n by ntree matrix, each
column containing the node number that the cases fall in for that tree.

I dont understand how this works? What is the node number that the cases fall in for that tree? Are a tree's nodes numbered when they are generated in this implementaiton of rf?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Each tree has a bunch of nodes. Each node gets a number. The matrix tells you which node each case lands in for each tree.

Comment: Thats exactly the answer I was looking for. If I want to look up the node and see what observations are associated I would apply this number to the tree in the forest? which means I must save the whole forest or...?